# Не получается умножить float на float

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

Есть датафрейм (df), полученный от Binance-API через импорт binance-python-connector в формате JSON, в котором хранятся float-значения (курс обмена), а также небольшой код, меняющий значения ячеек в столбце "unitPrice", умножая его на 0.1%:

```
response = client.c2c_trade_history("BUY")
df = pd.json_normalize(response, "data")
df["unitPrice"]=df.unitPrice*1.1
```

Выполнение данного кода приводило к ошибке:

> can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Я попытался поменять значения в столбце "unitPrice" на float, однако, прочитав заново ошибку, понял, что сделал абсолютно то же, что и привело к этой ошибке. Всё же прикреплю попытку:

```
response = client.c2c_trade_history("BUY")
df = pd.json_normalize(response, "data")
df["unitPrice"].astype(float)
df["unitPrice"]=df.unitPrice*1.1
```

Код ошибки идентичный:

> can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

**ВАЖНАЯ РЕМАРКА:**
Если попытаться изменить вид данных на integer в этом столбце, то это изменит и сам курс обмена, что мне категорически не нужно. Мне нужно получить именно float-значение с умножением на 0.1%.

Comment: вообще не имею понятия о Пандах и API, но гарантирую, что float на float вам умножат.  А еще знаю слово sequence на английском (Google Translate в помощь:-)). И логика говорит, что вы не единичное значение тут умножать  пытаетесь, а что-то типа списка. Потому вам Python и говорит, что на целое число раз он вам список не повторит. Разбирайтесь с тем, почему df["unitPrice"] - не число:-) Можете unitPrice без кавычек написать, например, для начала в квадратных скобках:-))

Comment: @Сергей Честно говоря, сразу бы и не додумался... Sequence воспринял как обычный текст, а не тип данных... Английский-программистский еще плох :) Спасибо! Я что-нибудь постараюсь придумать, однако не могу гарантировать, что я еще не вернусь с каким-нибудь похожим вопросом, ибо я еще совсем новичок :)

Comment: возвращайтесь, люблю отвечать о том, с чем не знаком - так интересно:-) Кстати, слово "последовательность" не является особо программистким, но в любом случае - Google Translate в помощь:-) .

Comment: @Сергей Я просто воспринял эту ошибку как обычный текст английского языка, хах. Только когда вижу int или что-то прям истинно-программистсткое - включается голова, что это ошибка. В общем просто пропустил слово, каким-то образом. Английский на уровне B2 и даже стыдно стало 0_о

Comment: @Сергей, `pandas.Sequence` можно умножать на числа. Это специальное свойство `pandas` - многие операции являются массовыми. Другое дело что последовательность **строк** можно умножить только на целое (результат будет как если бы каждую **строку** умножили на целое), а последовательность **чисел** можно умножать на любое число (результатом будет последовательность **произведений**).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо! Т.е. вы имеете в виду, что там просто строки были в dataframe.

Comment: qoopdata - проверите? У вас там строки в датафрейме? И да, как видим у @StanislavVolodarskiy - `astype` на месте не изменяет датафрейм. А я не угадал причину:-) (кроме "гарантирую, что float на float вам умножат")

Answer (score 0):

Воспроизведение ошибки. Предположим что датафрейм содержит не сами вещественные числа, а строки с изображениями вещественных чисел:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'unitPrice': ['1.', '2.']})
print(df)
print(df['unitPrice'] * 1.1)
```

> ```
> $ python temp.py
>   unitPrice
> 0        1.
> 1        2.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> ...
> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
> ```

Ошибка проявляется так как строки умножаются на вещественный коэффициент. Исправление состоит в приведении типа. Приведённые значения присваиваются обратно тому же столбцу:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'unitPrice': ['1.', '2.']})
print(df)
df['unitPrice'] = df['unitPrice'].astype(float)
print(df)
print(df['unitPrice'] * 1.1)
```

> ```
> $ python temp.py
>   unitPrice
> 0        1.
> 1        2.
>    unitPrice
> 0        1.0
> 1        2.0
> 0    1.1
> 1    2.2
> Name: unitPrice, dtype: float64
> ```

Умножение работает.

Comment: 1) А почему вы пишете "предположим"? 2) Т.е. ошибка автора в том, что он пошел верно, но `df["unitPrice"].astype(float)` неверно выполнил? Не сделал "df['unitPrice'] = "?

Comment: @Сергей, я не знаю что в том джейсоне. Такая ошибка будет если там строки, не числа.